# Simulate 100k transactions per second

Tags: jmeter

In JMeter(Vr. 5.2.1) i have JSR223 sampler having a custom script to generate a payload to an endpoint. The end point is capable of receiving 100000 transactions per second. However, from jmeter i find that the max samples i can achieve is around 4000 requests per second per thread.

I tried to increase the thread limit to 10 then 100, however the result seems to stay the same i.e., jmeter is able achieve a max of 4k requests per second.

i tried to have two thread groups running in parallel to increase transaction rate, this did not increase the rate beyond the 4k per second, mark, no matter what i do.

Is there any way or method i can use to increase this request rate to 100k per second?

The test plan has one thread group within which a simple controller and one jsr223 sampler withnin it. This is followed by a summary report at test plan level.

I have followed all the best practices highlighted in some of the articles in stackoverflow.

Thank you.

Comment: install jmeter on several machines... and run tests from several machines? https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html

Answer (score 0):

If you would really follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) you would be using [JMeter 5.5](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-5-5) as the very first one looks like:

> **16.1 Always use latest version of JMeter**
>
> The performance of JMeter is being constantly improved, so users are highly encouraged to use the most up to date version.

Given you applied all JMeter performance and tuning tips and [did the same to the JVM](https://www.uber.com/en-TR/blog/jvm-tuning-garbage-collection/) and still cannot reach more than 4000 transactions per second you can consider the following options:

1. Switch from JSR223 Sampler to a [Java Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Java_Request) sampler or create your own [JMeter Plugin](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_tutorial.html), in this case performance of your code would be higher
2. And consider switching to [distributed mode of JMeter tests execution](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.html), if you can reach 4000 requests per second from one machine you will need 25 machines to reach 100000 requests per second.

Comment: Thank you Dmitri & Marcel for your response. I think in this case, i will distribute the load across many remote machines and achive the goal.